# What is the best way to add iOS Google API components (Analytics) to a static iOS library?

Tags: ios, static-libraries, cocoapods, google-analytics-sdk

I am building a static iOS library and would like to use Google Analytics for tracking events inside the library. I tried installing via CocoaPods in the library itself but when I run the parent app I get a "resource not found" error. When I add the Google dependency in the podspec of the library via s.dependency and then run "pod instal" I get:

**[!] The 'Pods-MyApp' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries:**

and then when I run the app, I get this error:

**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI"**